# Converting int to char in array, returning memory pointers

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a 2d integer array to a 2d character array and am currently receiving memory or uninitialized values:

```
[I@210ace8d
[I@4c7e9bed
[I@c2f0bd7
[I@64b25680
```

How do you properly convert these arrays?

code is below

```
public static char[][] findCavities(int[][] map){
    char[][] charMap = new char[map.length][map.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){

            charMap[i] = map[i].toString().toCharArray();

    }

    return charMap;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `map[i].toString()` does and why do you think so?

Comment: it converts the integer array to a string which can then be converted to a character array.

Comment: What does it mean to _converts the integer array to a string_?

Comment: it makes an integer array such as {1,2,3} become a string "123"

Comment: Those are arrays.  Arrays of integers.  Or at least the `toString` representation of the same.

Comment: Not tell us why you think it will _makes an integer array such as {1,2,3} become a string "123"_. Where did you read that?

Comment: `String.valueOf(char[])`

Answer (score 0):

Java array's `.toString` implementation is brain dead, sorry. You could do `Arrays.toString(map[i])` instead, it would return a string looking like `"[1, 2, 3]"`. You could strip brackets and spaces from it with `.replaceAll("[\\[\\] ]", "")`, but that's really ugly :(

If you are using java 8, you could also do `Stream.of(map[i]).collect(Collectors.joining(""))`. That would return `"123"`.

Absent that, there are various libraries (like Apache commons) you could use to work around this deficiency in the standard libs, or just write your own code, that traverses the array, and builds the string from it element-by-element: `String s = ""; for(int i: array) s+=i;`

But what about two (or more) -digit numbers? You do realize, that your approach would convert an input like `{11, 1, 11}` into a char array `{'1', '1', '1', '1', '1'}`, just as it would do for `{111, 11}`, `{1,1,111}` etc., right? It seems to me that what you are doing isn't really what you want to do ...